# PDFBox - How to get the page index of a page by it's page-number

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a document where the first 3 pages are not labeled with any page-number (such as preface, table-of-contents etc.). Page numbering starts at page-index e.g. 4. How can I find the index of this page with page number 1, so I know that the main content starts at index 4 (Should be generic as page-numbering can start from any page-index)?

**Edit:**

PDDebugger shows that `Page: 15 - 1` is the first page. So I need the index of this page, which is 14.

[image]

**Edit:**
Here is the PageLabels tree object:

[image]

Comment: Could you please open the file with PDFDebugger and post a screenshot, and then explain what goes in and what goes out of your wished method?

Comment: @Tilman I assume the OP has a **PageLabels** number tree like `<</Nums [0 <</P (Cover)>> 1 <</S /r>> 39 <</S /D>>]>>` for which he wants to get the `39` as index of the first page label with a decimal page number. @onurhb Is that correct?

Comment: @onurhb please show the the **PageLabels** tree object. That the page in your viewer is named "15 - 1" is an interpretation of an entry of that number tree by your viewer.

Comment: @mkl How do I access PageLabels tree object? I am not experienced with pdfbox tools.

Comment: In PDFDebugger, click on "View", then "Show Internal Structure", then in the tree on "Root", then "PageLabels".

Comment: @mkl I have added screenshot. Page 1 starts at index 14 so you know :)

Comment: @onurhb Tilman's answer most likely is as good an answer as you will get. I probably would have tried differently (by analyzing the number tree entries instead looking at each page label until "1") but the results wouldn't have been better.

Comment: @mkl I always go for the lazy solution :-)

Comment: @mkl Thanks for helping me! I will consider your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple code to find the page with a specific label:

```
PDPageLabels pageLabels = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPageLabels();
String[] labels = pageLabels.getLabelsByPageIndices();
for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; ++i)
{
    if ("1".equals(labels[i]))
    {
        System.out.println("found: " + i);
        break;
    }
}
```

As pointed out by the OP,

```
System.out.println(pageLabels.getPageIndicesByLabels().get("1"));
```

works as well.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.

Comment: pageLabels.getPageIndicesByLabels() returns a map of page-number to index. So I don't need to use a for loop.